# Change a dataframe with one header to two headers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I want to change it to the others which I attached. The name of columns are not important, also the new one does not have index `0,1,2...`. This seems rather obvious, but I can't seem to figure out it. Note: I don't want to change the values and columns. I only have the same structure. I've added a simple dataframe as an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['timestamp'] =[ 1, 2]
df['cons_id'] = [2, 3]
df[ 'value'] = [ 4,5]
```

The dataframe which I have:

[image]

Here is the output that I want to change the dataframe to:

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what exactly do you want? What is in `bottom` that you are referring to?

Comment: what's the desired output given the provided `df`?

Comment: @aminrd  I've just updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `set_index`:

```
df = df.set_index('timestamp').rename_axis(columns='timestamp')
print(df)

# Output
timestamp  cons_id  value
timestamp                
1                2      4
2                3      5
```

Comment: One thing. Above the timestamp, we have another timestamp. with set_index, we don't have the extra timestamp.

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it please?